# Mapping flex fields to columns in task list (Oracle SOA Suite 11g)

Tags: oracle, soa, business-process-management

I have read in oracle documentation that it is possible to map the payload attributes of a task to the tasks list columns using flex fields, but I don't know how.
I already mapped the payload attributes to a flex field, when I search in the worklist any of these attributes the tasks list is filtered correctly, but in the edit view menu doesn't appear any of the flex fields to be selected as a visible column.

Someone knows how to configure this feature??

I'm using Oracle SOA Suite 11.1.1.3

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it:
I was trying to edit the Inbox view, creating a custom view actually shows the flex fields